# SQL - Grouping by content

Tags: sql

For example : I have 10 records.

```
 Name        | Count 
-------------+--------
Band 40m     |  5
Band 45m     |  3
Band 50m     |  2
Rope 100m    |  7
Rope 200m    |  12
Rope 300m    |  2
Rope 400m    |  5
Ancient Key  |  1
Rod          |  3
Pickaxe      |  3
```

And I want group all bands and all ropes with specific name 'SpecName' ;

```
 Name        | Count 
-------------+--------
SpecName     | 36                -> 5+3+2+7+12+2+5 = 36
Ancient Key  | 1
Rod          | 3
Pickaxe      | 3
```

Is this possible or not? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression for this:

```
select
    case 
        when name like 'Band %' or name like 'Rope %' then 'SpecName' 
        else name
    end name,
    sum(count) cnt
from mytable
group by 
    case 
        when name like 'Band %'  or name like 'Rope %' then 'SpecName' 
        else name
    end
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ecb98240786582ba2e41dc7cb9dac0f)**:

```
name        | cnt
:---------- | --:
SpecName    |  36
Ancient Key |   1
Rod         |   3
Pickaxe     |   3
```

Comment: Column 'MakineListe.MakineAdi' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Welcome  @HasanKaanTURAN! I just added a db fiddle to my answer for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression.  One possibility is to choose the three particulars you want and lump everything else together:

```
select (case when name in ('Ancient Key', 'Rod', 'Pickaxe')
             then name else specname
        end) as name,
       sum(count)
from t
group by (case when name in ('Ancient Key', 'Rod', 'Pickaxe')
               then name else specname
          end);
```

Comment: I need to reverse this event. I have 1000+ records and I can't write the others